# Can execute Linux command with SAS?

Tags: linux, command-line, sas, executable

I know SAS can execute UNIX command via this structure

```
X unixcommand1;unixcommand2;
```

or structure like this:

```
%sysexec %str(unixcommand1;unixcommand2;)
```

but I don't know if SAS can also execute LINUX command as well. If so, what is the structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS syntax for executing unix/linux/windows commands is the same for any OS (the command itself, of course, may differ).  As long as system option XCMD is enabled, you should be fine.